# Conditional query in PHP using using form field

Tags: php, wordpress

As a precursor, I am fairly new to all of this so apologies for any naivety. I am using a Wordpress plugin called dynamic.ooo which allows for custom conditions using PHP. I want to use this to show or hide a shortcode block based on the values being output in a form higher up on the page. This is what I currently have:

```
$voltage = $_POST['voltage'];
$amp = $_POST['amp'];
if ($voltage > 100 && $voltage < 150 && $amp > 35 && $amp < 45) {
    return true;
}
```

In Wordpress you can set the 'field id' of the form field, so I have set these to 'voltage' and 'amp', but I'm not sure I'm calling them correctly? Any help would be massively appreciated, thanks.

Currently when I save the page and test it, the shortcode doesn't show, even though with the values I'm entering in the form, it should. So I'm unsure if I'm using the right 'name' within $_POST (see screenshots below):

[This is what I can see looking at the field in Chrome dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxEcR.png)

[And this is what the field looks like in Elementor/Wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raHTd.png)

Comment: That should be correct. `print_r($_POST)` will show you if you have those indexes are defined. Also might want to use greater than or equal to if `100` and `150` are valid. Although an `id` won't be what defines the index to PHP, PHP uses the `name`s of inputs.

Comment: I'm unclear what your question is; did you test it and find that it did the wrong thing? How did you test, and what happened? Please click [edit] under your question and add some more details of what you need help with.

Comment: I've just added a couple of images - when I run it, nothing happens, but I would expect the shortcode block to show. I'm unsure if the value I'm using inside $_POST is correct. I've also tried using `form_fields[voltage]` as pictured in the first screenshot but that also didn't work